# How to join items of list, but use a different delimiter for the last item?

Tags: java

Given list like:

`List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList("George", "John", "Paul", "Ringo")`

I'd like to transform it to a string like this:

`George, John, Paul and Ringo`

I can do it with rather clumsy `StringBuilder` thing like so:

```
String nameList = names.stream().collect(joining(", "));
        if (nameList.contains(",")) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(nameList);
            builder.replace(nameList.lastIndexOf(','), nameList.lastIndexOf(',') + 1, " and");
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

Is there a bit more elegant approach? I don't mind using a library if needed.

**NOTES**:

- I could use an old `for` loop with an index, but I am not looking for such a solution
- There are no commas within the values (names)

Comment: Are commas ever within the values?

Comment: @Bohemian nope (noted that in the question)

Comment: Why not encapsulate its functionality in an external method? Something like `public String mixListOfNamesAndReplaceLastCommaWithAnd(List<String> names)`

Comment: @Anatoly well yes, but now we're talking about the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already did most of it I would introduce a second method "replaceLast" which is not in the JDK for java.lang.String so far:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class StringUtils {
 private static final String AND = " and ";
 private static final String COMMA = ", ";

 // your initial call wrapped with a replaceLast call
 public static String asLiteralNumeration(List<String> strings) {
    return replaceLast(strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(COMMA)), COMMA, AND);
 }

 public static String replaceLast(String text, String regex, String replacement) {
    return text.replaceFirst("(?s)" + regex + "(?!.*?" + regex + ")", replacement);
 }
}
```

You might change the delimiters and params as well. Here the test for your requirements so far:

```
@org.junit.Test
public void test() {
 List<String> names = Arrays.asList("George", "John", "Paul", "Ringo");
 assertEquals("George, John, Paul and Ringo", StringUtils.asLiteralNumeration(names));

 List<String> oneItemList = Arrays.asList("Paul");
 assertEquals("Paul", StringUtils.asLiteralNumeration(oneItemList));

 List<String> emptyList = Arrays.asList("");
 assertEquals("", StringUtils.asLiteralNumeration(emptyList));

}
```

Comment: Not bad, if I don't need to parameterize the delimiters it can be 

`return names.stream().collect(joining(", ")).replaceFirst("(?s),(?!.*?,)", " and");`

Comment: Yes, of course, you can modify it to a one-liner :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how elegant this is, but it works. The annoying part is that you have to reverse the `List`.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("George", "John", "Paul", "Ringo");
String andStr = " and ";
String commaStr = ", ";
int n = list.size();
String result = list.size() == 0 ? "" :
        IntStream.range(0, n)
                 .mapToObj(i -> list.get(n - 1 - i))
                 .reduce((s, t) -> t + (s.contains(andStr) ? commaStr : andStr) + s)
                 .get();
System.out.println(result);
```

However, I think the best solution is this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int n = list.size();
for (String string : list) {
    sb.append(string);
    if (--n > 0)
        sb.append(n == 1 ? " and " : ", ");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

It's clear, efficient, and obviously works. I don't think `Stream`s are a good fit for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may join all the elements except the last by using a sublist:

```
String nameList =
    names.isEmpty() ? "" :
        names.subList(0, names.size() - 1)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(firstDelimiter))
            + ((names.size() > 1) ? secondDelimiter + names.get(names.size() - 1) : names.get(0)) 
        ;
```

Personally, I don't like this approach because for non-array backed list implementations, the time of `List#get` may be O(n).

Tested here:

```
static String joinList(List<String> names) {
    return joinList(names, ", ", " and ");
}

static String joinList(List<String> names, String firstDelimiter, String secondDelimiter) {
    return names.isEmpty() ? "" :
        names.subList(0, names.size() - 1)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(firstDelimiter))
        + ((names.size() > 1) ? secondDelimiter+ names.get(names.size() - 1) : names.get(0)) 
        ;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(joinList(Arrays.asList("George", "John", "Paul", "Ringo")));
    System.out.println(joinList(Arrays.asList("Ringo")));
    System.out.println(joinList(Arrays.asList()));
    System.out.println(joinList(null)); //this one throws NPE as OP oddly requested
}
```

Here's an alternative implementation or joinList, which may make it clearer what actually happens:

```
static String joinList(List<String> names, String firstDelimiter, String secondDelimiter) {
    if (names.isEmpty()) {
         return "";
    } else if (names.size() == 1) {
         return names.get(0);
    } else {
        return names.subList(0, names.size() - 1)
                    .stream().collect(Collectors.joining(firstDelimiter))
             + secondDelimiter + names.get(names.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be tricky to use for an empty list and a list of 1 element only

Comment: @Xorty in case of an empty list, return an empty string ;).

Comment: in case of 1 element it'd return "and George" instead of "George" (unlike the original solution)

Comment: @Xorty you can put `if` instructions before to return the desired result, you know? Because based on your theory, both this and the other solution will throw `NullPointerException` if `names` is `null` and there's no null check anywhere.

Comment: and that's fine :) That code is doing exactly what it needs to do and it crashes exactly when it should crash. I was just looking for some more elegant way. Your solution is not bad, but it would require bunch of `if`-s in this scenario.

Comment: I added an implementation with more explicit flow control.  It may be easier to understand what it does that way (and it doesn't create an empty sublist in the single-element case).

Comment: @RasmusKaj I wanted to write that code but OP replied in comments: *I was just looking for some more elegant way. Your solution is not bad, but it would require bunch of if-s in this scenario* so I tried to avoid any if. Also, any decent programmer can understand what the code does, and creating an empty sublist won't hurt performance, at least by using the list implementations provided by the JDK.

Comment: Are you using the word "elegant" when they mean "short"?  While I personally like the ? : operator, I refuse to call any code that contains nested ? : operators "elegant".  :-)

Comment: @RasmusKaj I call *elegant* to high performance code, despite if it's written so badly that I need a rosetta stone to translate it into a more readable way and understand what the code is doing. But for OP, seems like *elegant* code is more human readable and shorter rather than other thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an Iterator, this works:

```
private static String specialJoin(Iterable<?> list, String sep, String lastSep) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final Iterator<?> i = list.iterator();
    if (i.hasNext()) {
        result.append(i.next());
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            final Object next = i.next();
            result.append(i.hasNext() ? sep : lastSep);
            result.append(next);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

It can probably be rewritten as a collector easily enough by someone who is familiar with that api.

Comment: This may be subjective, but I'd indeed argue that the original code is better than this :)

Comment: This is an _elegant_ solution, since it does not traverse the collection more than once and does not depend on the content of the last value in the list. :-)

Comment: I wrote an other answer, using the streams / collect api.  But in real life, I would use this Iterator-based method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant solution using the streams api:

```
String nameList = names.stream().collect(naturalCollector(", ", " and "));
```

Unfortunatley, it depends on this function, that could be stashed away in some utility class:

```
public static Collector<Object, Ack, String> naturalCollector(String sep, String lastSep) {
    return new Collector<Object, Ack, String>() {

        @Override public BiConsumer<Ack, Object> accumulator() {
            return (Ack a, Object o) -> a.add(o,  sep);
        }

        @Override public Set<java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        @Override public BinaryOperator<Ack> combiner() {
            return (Ack one, Ack other) -> one.merge(other, sep);
        }

        @Override public Function<Ack, String> finisher() {
            return (Ack a) -> a.toString(lastSep);
        }

        @Override public Supplier<Ack> supplier() {
            return Ack::new;
        }

    };
}
```

... and also on this class, which is an internal stateholder in the above function, but which the Collector API wants exposed:

```
class Ack {
    private StringBuilder result = null;
    private Object last;

    public void add(Object u, String sep) {
        if (last != null) {
            doAppend(sep, last);
        }
        last = u;
    }

    private void doAppend(String sep, Object t) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            result.append(sep);
        }
        result.append(t);
    }

    public Ack merge(Ack other, String sep) {
        if (other.last != null) {
            doAppend(sep, last);
            if (other.result != null) {
                doAppend(sep, other.result);
            }
            last = other.last;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String toString(String lastSep) {
        if (result == null) {
            return last == null ? "" : String.valueOf(last);
        }
        result.append(lastSep).append(last);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A custom collector indeed is an elegant approach. Now it's just a matter of taste whether most of the developers are happier to understand few lines of string concatenations or custom collectors.

Comment: This is my first attempt at writing a custom collector, so it can probably be improved on ...

Comment: @RasmusKaj I think it's really good. It certainly works. The only improvement I'd make is that all those anonymous classes in `naturalCollector` can be replaced by lambdas. The code for `supplier()` can be just `return Ack::new;`.

Answer (score 0):

If commas are never in the values, it's a one-liner:

```
String all = names.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "").replaceAll(",(?!.*,)", " and");
```

Comment: It can become a nightmare to someone to support this code :(

Comment: While we're on the topic of supporting this code... could you break the answer down and explain its parts?

Answer (score -2):

You can have write a custom function to add the last delimiter, but for delimiter in between you can use StringUtils.join() to accomplish your task.Check this link for [api](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(byte[],%20char))

Comment: I don't even need that, I already joined them with plain Java 8 - see `collect(joining(", "))` part